# Hide spinner on iOS Cordova inAppBrowser

Tags: ios, cordova, spinner, inappbrowser

When running InAppBrowser in iOS device and when I click on some LINK, then some spinner shows up, before the web loads. But on android inAppBrowser it does not.
How can I hide this spinner on iOS device?
I have been searching for solution, but nothing found yet.
Is there some inappbrowser option for hidding spinner?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the InAppBrowser called hidespinner

hidespinner: Set to yes or no to change the visibility of the loading indicator (defaults to no).

More info can be found here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/